# How do use a sort on a hash in a for

Tags: sorting, hash, raku

I have a hash `%h` and I want to process the data in a `for` statement in alphabetical order of keys.

But if I use a `sort` on the hash I get a list of `Pair`s, which is understandable. But how do I unpack this for a `for` statement.

Currently I'm using the following:

```
my %h = <xabsu ieunef runf awww bbv> Z=> 1..*; # create a hash with random key names
for %h.sort { 
  my ($name, $num) = (.key, .value);
  say "name: $name, num: $num"
}
# Output
# name: awww, num: 4
# name: bbv, num: 5
# name: ieunef, num: 2
# name: runf, num: 3
# name: xabsu, num: 1
```

But I would prefer something like the more idiomatic form:

```
my %h = <xabsu ieunef runf awww bbv> Z=> 1..*; # create a hash with random key names
for %h.sort -> $name, $num {   
  say "name: $name, num: $num"
}
# Output
# name: awww       4, num: bbv       5
# name: ieunef     2, num: runf      3
# Too few positionals passed; expected 2 arguments but got 1
#   in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

I'm sure there is a neater way to 'unpack' the Pair into a signature for the `for` statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The neater way:

```
for %h.sort -> (:key($name), :value($num)) {
```

This destructures the `Pair` by calling `.key` and `.value` on it, and then binding them to `$name` and `$num` respectively.

Perhaps a shorter, more understandable version:

```
for %h.sort -> (:$key, :$value) {
```

which would create variables with the same names the methods got called with.

Comment: And because TIMTOWTDI / if you hate parentheses, you can also do `for %h.sort.kv -> $name, $num { ... }` (I know lizmat++ knows this, pointing this out for other users)

Comment: Have you tried that?  The `sort` creates a `Seq` of `Pairs`, a `kv` on that creates a `Seq` of intermixed integers and `Pair`s.  Try running this: `my %h = a => 42, b => 666; for %h.sort.kv -> $key, $value { dd $key, $value }`

Comment: Oops, indeed, it does, definitely a brain brainfart moment there  =/

Comment: The correct form of `kv` after `sort` would be either `for %h.sort.map(*.kv) -> ($k, $v) { ... }`, OR `for %h.sort.map(|*.kv) -> $k, $v { ... }`

Comment: /me remembers adding the Pair.kv method just for that  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Raising @Joshua 's comment to an answer, a neater way is:

```
%h.sort.map(|*.kv) -> $name,$num { ... }
```

This uses two Raku features:

- `*` inside the map is the Whatever star to create a closure
- `|` flattens the resultant list, so that after `->` the `$name, $num` variables do not need to be inside parens.